# Do generics allow you break type safety in Java?

Tags: java, type-safety

It appears that I have found a case where you can break Java's type safety using generics.  Observe the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static List<Integer> aMethod(){
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("this is not an int");
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> aList = aMethod();
        System.out.println(aList.get(0) + 1);
    }
}
```

The above code is perfectly legal according to Java JDK version 1.8.0_144.  Notice that `aMethod` purports to return a `List<Integer>` but does not complain that I'm returning a `List` without a type specified for the generic.  Indeed, that list contains a string.

I am able to compile the code, and not surprisingly, when I run the main method I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

because I'm trying to add a `String` to an `int`.  Is this a bug in the JDK?  It seems like a huge oversight.

Comment: Generics - no. Raw types - yes.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of situations like this. Java has 'weak generics' (whatever the technical term is.) Certain IDEs (NetBeans) allow for turning on warnings or errors for these kinds of problems.

Comment: JVM simply doesn't allow type mismatch operations to occur because java has very tight type safety

Comment: You should be getting a compiler warning that tells you that this is unsafe and why, and the compiler will be correct.

Comment: Using raw types (or using generics incorrectly) can cause bad things? That's surprising. ... well, no, actually it isn't.